# Download base64 file cordova android (via javascript)

Tags: android, reactjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Website(ReactJs) with a pdf download functionality(via base64) and it works fine. For Android, I have a cordova app where the app is pointed to website and no actual app code resides inside cordova and this is where the problem starts.

The PDF download is not working in app and I have been restricted from using native java code or Cordova(js + file-plugin).

Is there any way to achieve this with given constraints?